# Affine-regular hexagon in convex body

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry, affine-geometry

An affine-regular $n$-gon is a non-degenerate affine image of the regular $n$-gon. It seems to be a standard fact in combinatorial geometry that inside every convex compact set $K\subseteq \mathbb R^2$ with nonempty interior it is possible to inscribe at least one affine-regular hexagon so that its vertices belong to the boundary of $K$. This is stated, for example, [here](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/EMIS/journals/AG/3-1/3_45.pdf).

How does one prove this? I am not able to find an accessible reference that contains the proof. Is there "typically" a unique inscribed hexagon?

Thanks

Comment: Paper by Besicovitch cited on your reference is ok, is not it?
Here is a text https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15433464/besicovitch1948.pdf

Comment: Great thanks! I was not able to find that paper. Do you know of any results on uniqueness? The proof contains a partial answer.

Comment: I am afraid that in general there is no uniqueness, consider a disc.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487594